# A simple dilemma I'm having involving defining and calling 2 functions that make use of each other in Python

Tags: python, function, user-input

So I'm learning how to program with Python (my first programming language) and I'm a complete newbie with it. I'm using inventwithpython as well as codecademy.com. The thing with codecademy is that they really aren't that good at teaching programming from what I am comparing it towards with inventwithpython. On one of the tutorials on there they want me to define two functions and call them using each other. I think I'm very close to doing this correctly and I feel the right way of doing this is staring me right in the face. So here is the code:

```
def cube(number2):
    pine =  number2**3 
    return pine

def by_three(number2):
    if number2 % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number2)
    else:
        return False

number2 = raw_input("Pick a number")

by_three(number2)
```

And here is the error I get from the interface:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 13, in <module>
  File "python", line 6, in by_three
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I tried converting that pine to a string format, but didn't work, so I just reverted it back. Codecademy sucks in my opinion and I'm just using it because I can't find many good sources other than the inventwithpython site to learn how to program with Python.

Comment: Is this your whole code? It says "line 6 in by_three", but there are only 4 lines in the function

Comment: @Haidro Yes, it is the whole code. I think it means that it's the 6 line in the whole code which is located in the def by_three block.

Comment: It doesn't mean that :p, but when I run it I get `line 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input()` returns a *string*. And you're trying to use the modulo expression with a string, which is why you are getting that error.

Convert the string to an integer with the [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
number2 = int(raw_input("Pick a number"))
```

By the way, codecademy isn't that bad :p. It just gets confusing because different authors create different tutorials.

Comment: I'm going to keep using codecademy, but mostly more like a secondary tool to inventwithpython. Codecademy I realize is good, but it has many glitches like with this problem I was having I saved it and ran it, and, although it didn't work properly with the interpreter, the site itself still gave the green arrow to continue onto my next lesson which I did not want to do since I really didn't do it right.

Comment: @DavidTheDreamerBenditt Yes, it's very buggy. If you're having problems, the site actually has a forum which you can check out

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. It's very ironic because for a site that teaches coding and mastery of programming, its site is loaded with bugs. :P

Answer (score 2):

You did not typecast the number. Use the `int()` function to do that.

```
def cube(number2):
    pine = number2**3
    return pine

def by_three(number2):
    if number2 % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number2)
    else:
        return False

number2 = int(raw_input("Pick a number"))

print by_three(number2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You guys answer really fast :) I hope to become very proficient in Python and then in C++, but right now I'm just trying to overcome these simple obstacles that only noobs like myself trip over :P

Comment: @DavidTheDreamerBenditt I started on Python some time ago. I know the problem with codecademy as I used it too. Try [link](http://docs.python.org/2/index.html) the tutorials out. You can download them in html format for easy viewing. These are helping me a lot.